# Convert Json to actual Javascript on server side for inclusion in C# ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string on the server back end that javascript needs to access on the client side. I currently send this string as Json in the page, and wrap it in a JSON.Parse() on the client side. This works fine.

More out of curiosity than anything- Is there a way to convert the Json string into actual javascript code, on the server side, so that I could include this code in the page as actual inline javascript code, and not have to parse it on the client then? Preferably with Newtonsoft/JSON.Net but really any Json lib on the back end. Effectively a "deserialize to javascript as a string" option.

I know VS Code has a "past JSON as Javascript", so this is pretty much what I'm looking to do, but at runtime.

Comment: Yes. If I remember correctly you can add a script tag to your razor page which will have something like `myVar = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(someJsonString))`. But it's been some time since I have done something like that.

Comment: The JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript, so JSON encoded data is already valid JavaScript.

Comment: I'd like to make the non-serialized version of the json. And not on the client side (as Json.parse does).

Comment: But why? What's the actual end goal? Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: it's a. so can include actual javascript in my page, and b. just to see if there's a supported way to do this that I'm overlooking... and c. just for fun

Comment: Seconding the above comment, JSON *is* "actual javascript code". You're going to have to have to provide an example of what your "json string" is and what your desired output looks like (what "paste JSON as Javascript" outputs?) if anyone is going to answer this.

Comment: I'll take this as a no... ;)